# How to find close surfaces in a triangle mesh?

Tags: 3d, mesh, topology

I have a triangle mesh than may contain many isolated closed surfaces. For example, the triangle mesh may contain two cubic boxes. How can I identify those closed surfaces?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Create a graph where node is a mesh triangle and two nodes are connected if triangles share an edge. On that graph find all [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) as described on same [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)#Algorithms).